# How to create a ICNS icon programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage, cgimageref, icns

OK this is what I want :

- Take some `NSImage`s
- Add them to an `ICNS` file
- Save it

This is what I've done so far (purely as a test) :

```
- (CGImageRef)refFromImage:(NSImage*)img
{
    CGImageSourceRef source;

    source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)[img TIFFRepresentation], NULL);
    CGImageRef maskRef =  CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);

    return maskRef;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSImage* img1 = [NSImage imageNamed:@"image1"];
    NSImage* img2 = [NSImage imageNamed:@"image2"];

    NSLog(@"%@",img1);
    CGImageRef i1 = [self refFromImage:img1];
    CGImageRef i2 = [self refFromImage:img2];

    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[@"~/Documents/final.icns" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]]; 
    CGImageDestinationRef dr = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fileURL, kUTTypeAppleICNS , 1, NULL);

    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dr, i1, NULL);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dr, i2, NULL);
    /* Even tried adding 'multiple' times

    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dr, i1, NULL);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dr, i2, NULL);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dr, i1, NULL);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dr, i2, NULL);

    */

    CGImageDestinationFinalize(dr);

    CFRelease(dr);
}
```

But, it still keeps throwing an error :

> ImageIO:   CGImageDestinationFinalize image destination does
>   not have enough images

What's wrong with my code?

---

I've had a look at the answers below, but still nothing :

- [Save CGImageRef to PNG file errors? (ARC Caused?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225838/save-cgimageref-to-png-file-errors-arc-caused)
- [How exactly to make a CGImageRef from an image on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550201/how-exactly-to-make-a-cgimageref-from-an-image-on-disk)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478925/objective-c-convert-an-image-to-icns/15663459#15663459

Comment: You're adding two images but you passed 1 as the `count` argument of `CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [IconFamily](http://iconfamily.sourceforge.net/).

> IconFamily is a Cocoa/Objective-C wrapper for the Mac OS X Carbon
>   API's "icon family" data type. Its main purpose is to enable Cocoa
>   applications to easily create custom file icons from NSImage
>   instances, and thus take advantage of Mac OS X's high-resolution RGBA
>   "thumbnail" icon formats to provide richly detailed thumbnail previews
>   of the files' contents.

```
NSImage *mImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/Username/Desktop/WhiteTiger.jpg"];
IconFamily *fam = [IconFamily iconFamilyWithThumbnailsOfImage:mImage];    
[fam writeToFile:@"/Users/Username/Desktop/WhiteTiger.icns"];
```

Comment: Note, that the current Version of IconFamily (0.9.4) doesn't work on Macs with Retina Displays. (HDPI)

Comment: There's an updated version of IconFamily that works on retina here:

https://github.com/sveinbjornt/IconFamily