# Change OSX Notification Center icon at runtime

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter, nsusernotification

Is there (now) a officially supported way to change the OSX Notification Center's Icon for NSUserNotifications while my App is running?
I searched the web, but the answers weren't really "recent", so I just wanted to double check.

I'd like to show the currently playing spotify track's Artwork next to it's title / name

What I tried until now is really ugly:

1. temporarily replacing the CFBundleIconFile of my app with a [IconFamily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12315845/1595285) generated .icns file (I know i shouldn't modify anthing inside the bundle, but I'm not aiming to get the app to the App Store)
2. restart Notification Center to "forget" it's eventually cached icons

   NSRunningApplication* notificationCenter = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.notificationcenterui"];
   [notificationCenter terminate];

   (i know I REALLY SHOULDN'T do this)

Comment: Hi @blub, have you found a solution to this?

Comment: no, stopped searching/trying a couple of days after my post here, sorry

Comment: It's sad. I don't see why Apple would need to make this so hard... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are **NOT** going to submit your app to App Store, there's a private API in 10.9 that does what iTunes did:

```
NSUserNotification *notification = [NSUserNotification new];
[notification setValue:anImage forKey:@"_identityImage"];
```

[image]