How to get the 'com.apple.icns' data of a file for filling the pasteboard?
When one copies a file in Finder, the pasteboard contains a 'icns' type with the various icon descriptions of the copied item(s).
I need to accomplish the same effect in my code, i.e. generate the data I can put into the pasteboard for the com.apple.icns type.
How do I collect the data for this type? All I can find in AppKit are functions for getting an NSImage for a file, but nothing that gives me the icns resource.

Okay, so what's the input for generating the data? Do you want to get it for a particular file? Or do you just want to know how icns data should be structured?

The input is the icon information that the Finder has and that it would put into the Clipboard if you Copy the file. I am writing a program that mimics the Finder's behavior, for any file.

@ThomasTempelmann: Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12315845/1187415 is a link to a GitHub project https://github.com/sveinbjornt/IconFamily which claims to be able to read and write .icns data. I haven't tried it. It is written in Objective-C and uses many deprecated APIs, but perhaps you can get some ideas from there.

@MartinR Thank you for finding that for me. Yes, it contains a function, based on the deprecated GetIconRefFromFileInfo, that does what I need. If you'd please turn this into an answer, so that I can mark it as resolved.

@ThomasTempelmann: If you have a working solution then you are welcome to post that as a (self) answer.

Here's code, using deprecated functions (but there's no modern alternative, apparently):
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

NSData* icnsOfFileAtPath (NSString *path)
{
    // based on https://github.com/sveinbjornt/IconFamily
    CFURLRef urlRef = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)path, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
    if (!urlRef) {
        return nil;
    }
    FSRef fsRef;
    bool ok = CFURLGetFSRef (urlRef, &fsRef);
    CFRelease (urlRef);
    if (!ok) {
        return nil;
    }
    IconRef iconRef;
    SInt16  label;
    OSStatus res = GetIconRefFromFileInfo (&fsRef, 0, NULL, kFSCatInfoNone, NULL, kIconServicesNormalUsageFlag, &iconRef, &label);
    if (res) {
        return nil;
    }
    IconFamilyHandle ifh;
    res = IconRefToIconFamily (iconRef, kSelectorAllAvailableData, &ifh);
    ReleaseIconRef (iconRef);
    NSData *icns = [NSData dataWithBytes:*ifh length:GetHandleSize((Handle)ifh)];
    DisposeHandle ((Handle)ifh);
    return icns;
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop


The deprecation of GetIconRefFromFileInfo states that you should use NSWorkspace iconForFile: instead. I have no idea if that's a workable solution for your case.

@HangarRash: I spent some time on this problem and I found no way to get the icns data out of the NSImage that iconForFile returns.

@MartinR This certainly isn't the first time Apple has deprecated something and the supposed replacement isn't really a valid replacement. Oh well.

macOS has an iconutil command line tool which can create icns files. Interestingly, this is linked agains the private IconServices framework  (as can be seen from otool -L /usr/bin/iconutil).

@MartinR Since my app doesn't require sandboxing I could probably use the private API. I'll have a look with Hopper inside.

@ThomasTempelmann: What I noticed: The 'icns' item in the pasteboard contains an icon of type 'FD D9 2F A8' when copying a file in the Finder. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Icon_Image_format that is for the dark mode. The icns from GetIconRefFromFileInfo does not contain that icon.
